# Why does RoboCopy create a hidden system folder?

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

I thought I would try out RoboCopy for mirroring the contents of a folder to another harddrive. And seems like it worked. But, for some reason, to see the destination folder I have to both enable *Show hidden files, folders and drives* and disable *Hide protected operating system files*. Why is this? Both the source and destination folder was initially both visible and normal directories. When I open up the properties for that destination folder, the *Hidden* attribute is even disabled. What is going on here?

Is it because I ran it in an administrator command prompt? Or is it an issue with my choice of modifiers? Or does robocopy really just work this way?

> ```
> robocopy E: I:\E /COPYALL /E /R:0 /MIR /B /ETA
> ```

---

***Update:*** Tried to copy another drive to another folder, and I got the same thing happening there. But when I try to just copy a folder to a different folder, then the destination folder stays normal. Could it be because I copy a drive? If so, how can I prevent this from happening? Cause I really do want to copy the whole drive...

Comment: Creating the directory ahead of time does not work. As soon as your run the robo copy again, the attributes once again make it hidden. The attribute command does work.

Comment: I'm stuck in this boat as well.  Destination folder gets hidden every time, can't make it stop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On my system (Vista), powershell shows the c:\ drive as having both hidden and system attributes set.

```
    PS C:\Users\michael.DOMAIN> Get-Item c:\


    Directory:


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d--hs     8/18/2009 12:19 PM        <DIR> C:\
```

After copying the files, you can use attrib to fix them. Check out attrib /? for details.

Comment: Hm, yeah, all my three hard drives have those attributes as well... Weird thing is that my D and E drives got a hidden system folder when I robocopied them to folders on an external drive, while the C drive didn't O.o I don't get this...

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a hidden network share (`$`). I ran `Get-Item` on that share and it also says `d--hs` so I guess that's the reason! Thanks!

Comment: This can also be true of network shares in general, such as from our Synology NAS box, that marks \\nas\sharename as a hidden folder. When you copy that folder with robocopy with the /copyall or /COPY:xAxxxx that includes (A)ttributes the destination folder is created with the same attributes as the source.

Answer (score 10):

It has to do with copying the hidden/system System Volume Information from the root of a disk - if it gets copied, the target directory gets the same attributes system/hidden.

Creating the directory before copying does not help as robocopy will hide it too.

Add the `/A-:SH` switch to ignore system files.

More information in this [Microsoft Technet discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8dcb6432-6ae0-4816-92e8-2599e5e638f5/robocopy-hides-destination-directory?forum=w7itprogeneral).

Comment: /A-:SH doesn't work for me in Powershell.  Still gets hidden every time.

Answer (score 7):

I have also ran into this problem.  It seems like this hidden folder comes up when the source directory is a root of the drive, eg.  `D:\` or `F:\`.  These folders will contain the system and hidden attributes, and being a source root folder, it can't be removed by the `attrib -s -h` command.

In this example, `F:\` is the source `G:\` is the destination.

You can see the attributes in PowerShell.  You'll see the mode `d--hs` for directory, hidden & system.  Try the `get-item` command `C:\> Get-Item F:\`

Robocopy supposedly will not create it as a hidden folder if the folder exists.  I've read on a few posts that using a `/CREATE` will do the trick, or you can create the folders manually ahead of time.  I have to do further testing as well as other combinations to verify this fully.

Otherwise, you can do a `attrib -h -s G:\Destination_Folder` to remove the system and hidden attribute after the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use M Aguilar's solution if you don't mind running `attrib` afterwards. Another solution would be to just create the target directory beforehand:

1. `mkdir I:\E`
2. `robocopy E: I:\E /COPYALL /E /R:0 /MIR /B /ETA`

Comment: This does not help - E is set to hidden system after the copy.